# jquery hover over one element, highlights all elements

Tags: jquery

When I hover over one element, all of them are highlighted, here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("p").hover(function(){
            $("p").css("background-color","yellow");
            },function(){
            $("p").css("background-color","transparent");
            });
```

I was wondering if I could highlight only one at a time instead of adding a class manually to each one

Comment: so wht do you want to do ? use a class insted of 'p'

Comment: I was wondering if I could highlight only one at a time instead of adding a class manually to each one.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This sounds like it can be done purely via CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use `$(this)`

insted of

> ```
>         $("p").hover(function(){
>         $("p").css("background-color","yellow");
>         },function(){
>         $("p").css("background-color","transparent");
>         });
> ```

use

```
        $("p").hover(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
        },function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","transparent");
        });
```

Comment: should of known :P ...THANK YOU :)

Answer (score 3):

you are targeting every `p` in the document. you need to restrict it

**EDIT: removed first part of answer**
answer provided by @littletipz is much better. second part still stands though...

**OR a CSS only example**

http://jsfiddle.net/bvsTg/

```
p:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to have effects to all elements at once, you can use this stop function:

```
    $("p").hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().css("background-color","yellow");
    },function(){
        $(this).stop().css("background-color","transparent");
    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/stop/